# Application crashes when started using CLR Profiler

Tags: wpf, clrprofiler

I am trying to use CLR Profiler for my WPF application, but the app crashes every time. Upon finding the Trace log for the application I got that in my app's `MainNavigation.xmal.cs` uses a Singleton class to store global data. When I start the app from profiler it somehow fails to initialize the Singleton class mentioned. Has anyone out here faced this kind of a issue?

Comment: Which version of CLR Profiler are you using? 4.0?

Comment: I am using CLR Profiler for the .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try CLR Profiler 4. You can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1)

I'm not sure how well v2 works with WPF apps, if at all.